# Can I download an Azure SQL backup from Get-AzSqlDatabaseGeoBackup?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I run the following in PowerShell:

```
Get-AzSqlDatabaseGeoBackup -ResourceGroupName "ContosoResourceGroup" -ServerName "ContosoServer"
```

It lists all the backups for the databases, specifically the ResourceId for each.

Now the resource id I assume is a blob because they are db backups?

How do I copy that blob to a storage account in Azure using `az cli`?

Comment: The **Resource ID** is not a blob, its essential for uniquely identifying and referencing Azure resources when performing operations such as management, monitoring, or automation using Azure APIs, PowerShell cmdlets, Azure CLI, or Terraform.

You may use the **az sql db export** command to export a database backup to a file storage account in **bacpac** file format.

Comment: Ok noted. I am using the az sql db export but for the admin uer name and password , must it be the admin user and password created when the sql server was provisioned or can i create a new user that can perform export of a database ?

Comment: Create a new user and assign the admin role to same user and try to execute the same cmd again.

Comment: Reset admin pwd using cmdlets:

$ServerPassword = "<New Password>"
$SecureString = ConvertTo-SecureString $ServerPassword -AsPlainText -Force
Set-AzSqlServer -ResourceGroupName "<RG_name>" -ServerName "<Server-Name>" -SqlAdministratorPassword $secureString

Comment: I have assigned admin role to the user via ALTER ROLE db_ddladmin ADD MEMBER [testuser];

Comment: what do you mean by rest admin pwd in the line Reset admin pwd using cmdlets: $ServerPassword = "<New Password>" $SecureString = ConvertTo-SecureString $ServerPassword -AsPlainText -Force Set-AzSqlServer -ResourceGroupName "<RG_name>" -ServerName "<Server-Name>" -SqlAdministratorPassword $secureString  ????

Comment: the issue is i do backups every second day ... so i cant really reset it every time. I already have a admin and password and if i use that it seems to work . There must be some role or permission not set ??

Comment: on another note cant i download the backups in Azure that are performed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now the resource id I assume is a blob because they are db backups?

Agreed with @Venkat V  The **Resource ID** is not a blob, its essential for uniquely identifying and referencing Azure resources when performing operations such as management, monitoring, or automation using Azure APIs, PowerShell cmdlets, Azure CLI, or Terraform.

> How do I copy that blob to a storage account in Azure using `az cli`?

- **Azure CLI**
  you need to use  [az sql db export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sql/db?view=azure-cli-latest#az-sql-db-export) as following command here you can use both SQL user credentials or admin user and password created when the SQL server was provisioned.

[image]

```
az sql db export -s ServerName -n DatabaseName -g ResourceGroupName --admin-password "password" --admin-user "SQL username/ AD usename" --auth-type ADPassword/SQL --storage-key Storage_account_key== --storage-key-type StorageAccessKey --storage-uri "https://StorageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/Folder1/myBacpac1.bacpac"
```

Answer (score 0):

The automated backups created by SQL Azure are stored internally on Azure and this is not directly exposed to you so you cannot download them or copy them to Azure Storage accounts. The process of restoring has been abstracted from you also, there is a restore interface and you just tell it from which point in time you would like to restore. SQL Azure does all the work to go through from the most recent full backup and re-apply changes to get to the point you requested.